# How to check is Image is already cached in android mobile using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I am storing my image and its reduced size image (blurred) in my Amazon Server, and store both path in database.

Now I want to know how to show blurred image first if original image is not cached and on clicking download it will download original Image. I am using Glide here...

I tried this

```
Glide.with(this)
           .load(mainUrl)
           .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
           .thumbnail(Glide.with(this)
                .load(url)                                            
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE))
           .centerCrop()
           .into(imageView);
```

but problem is It automatically download original image in background.

Comment: You actually required to set the blurred image as a placeholder. Glide Builder class provide you to set a placeholder method.

Comment: @Marcin how to check before showing Image it is already cached or not

Comment: not sure what you need to do that for. See this thread: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/509

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Glide.with(TheActivity.this)
   .load("http://sampleurl.com/sample.gif")
   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
   .into(theImageView);
```

Your code will prevent Glide from downloading the GIF and will only show the GIF if it is already cached, which it sounds like you don't want.

- Yes, the old image will eventually be removed. By default Glide uses an LRU cache, so when the cache is full, the least recently used image will be removed. You can easily customize the size of the cache to help this along if you want. See the Configuration wiki page for how to change the cache size.
- Unfortunately there isn't any way to influence the contents of the cache directly. You cannot either remove an item explicitly, or force one to be kept. In practice with an appropriate disk cache size you usually don't need to worry about doing either. If you display your image often enough, it won't be evicted. If you try to cache additional items and run out of space in the cache, older items will be evicted automatically to make space.

Answer (score 6):

I asked in Glide Github.
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2051

So add `apply(RequestOptions.onlyRetrieveFromCache())` to your `RequestOptions`. You can register a listener and `onFailed` gets called when no image is in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show placeholder before image is loading then use code below:-

```
Glide.with(this)
           .load(mainUrl)
           .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
           .placeholder("provide placeholder image here")
           .thumbnail(Glide.with(this)
                .load(url)                                            
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE))
           .centerCrop()
           .into(imageView);
```

Comment: I don't want to use placeholder. I have two image in my database table (first one is original image and second is reduced size of original image (blured image)). First time I want to show blured image with download Icon and after clicking icon it will download original image and show.

Comment: I wans to know how to check is original image is already cached or not .

Comment: Please find the solution here(https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/712) hope it will helps

Answer (score 0):

Another way  to detect this when you already loading images is to check `dataSource: DataSource` [param in RequestListener](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/440/com/bumptech/glide/request/RequestListener.html#onResourceReady-R-java.lang.Object-com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target-com.bumptech.glide.load.DataSource-boolean-)